# Value Function for java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap() returning constant value

Tags: java, function, stream, java-stream

I am trying to create a Map, where keys run value from 1 to N, and values are some constant for each of these kesys-

```
 private Map<Integer, Integer> getInitialDistMap(int N) {
    Function<Integer, Integer> constant = x -> Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, N).collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), constant));
}
```

This construct is giving me error.

Answer (score 1):

`IntStream.rangeClosed()` returns an `IntStream` and not a `Stream<Integer>`. An `IntStream` is a primitive Stream of `int`s. To transform an `IntStream` to a `Stream<Integer>` you need to call [`IntStream.boxed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#boxed--) on your stream:

```
private Map<Integer, Integer> getInitialDistMap(int N) {
    Function<Integer, Integer> constant = x -> Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, N).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), constant));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## static IntStream rangeClosed(int startInclusive,int endInclusive)

`rangeClosed` will return the `IntStream` and the only collect method available on `IntStream` is

```
<R> R collect(Supplier<R> supplier,ObjIntConsumer<R> accumulator, BiConsumer<R,R> combiner)
```

So use `boxed()` which returns `Stream<Integers>` stream of Integers and then collect to `Map`

```
Stream<Integer> boxed()
```

> Returns a Stream consisting of the elements of this stream, each boxed to an Integer.

**Solution**

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, N).boxed().collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), constant));
```